# Jquery Datatable export to pdf is not doing column wrapping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> ```
>   $('#example').dataTable({
>            
>             dom: 'Bfrtip',
>             buttons: [
>                 {
>                     extend: 'excelHtml5',
>                     title: 'Excel',
>                     text:'Export to excel'
>                     //Columns to export
>                     //exportOptions: {
>                    //     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
>                    // }
>                 },
>                 {
>                     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
>                     title: 'PDF',
>                     text: 'Export to PDF',
>                     //Columns to export
>                     exportOptions: {
>                         columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
>                     }
>                 }
>             ]
>         });
>         
>         $('#example td').css('white-space','initial');
> ```

I uploaded the sample code in jsfiddle, while i go for pdf its some of the columns values not wrapping

https://jsfiddle.net/mhdakta/gtps8cLb/13/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add customize, to pdf export the css also on pdf

```
 $('#example').dataTable({
               
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: 'Excel',
                        text:'Export to excel'
                        //Columns to export
                        //exportOptions: {
                       //     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                       // }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        title: 'PDF',
                        text: 'Export to PDF',
                        //Columns to export
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                        },
                        customize: function (doc) {
                           doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 8; //2, 3, 4,etc
                           doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10; //2, 3, 4, etc
                           doc.content[1].table.widths = [ '63%',  '13%', '13%', '13%'];
                       }
                    }
                ]
            });
            
            $('#example td').css('white-space','initial');
```

Comment: but for long word it is not wrapping

Comment: it go for wrapping the word between had space